# Data Driven Testing for a database web application

Tags: database, selenium, jmeter, selenium-webdriver, data-driven-tests

I have a database web application and I need to see all the possible inputs and all the possible outputs of this application (using Selenium or Jmeter).

Actually I tried to understand how the "Input Coverage Method" works in software testing tools but it seems too tough. If I'm not wrong this kind of testing I'm trying to do is a kind of Data Driven testing (means figuring out all the possible input and output of an database web application).

Would you please give a suggestion if there is any tool (I prefer open source) that can do this or any method to create such that test?
Do I have to create it by my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to create Equivalence Classes that cover most of your input dataset.
After that you can simply run your selenium/JMeter tests with the test data created.

You just need to create single test script and populate the test data in excel or CSV sheets to perform data driven driven testing.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.                                      Would you please tell me how I have to create Equivalence Classes? And How to create single test script?                             I'm totally new with this subjects.

Comment: Hi Amir, you seems to be in a hurry. First take some time out to make a decision on the tool you would like to use.
If you want to use JMeter and your application is not complex you can simply record and playback your test script with different dataset. 
Please refer to "Record and playback" and "Parameterization" posts in this blog performancetestingwithjmeter.blogspot.com

Answer (score 1):

Have a look a [jBehave](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-tutorial).

It's a BBD tool that can drive selenium and supports sets of input test data.

I've used it and it works well. You'll need patience to get through the glue code, but once you're out the other side you'll be glad you persevered.

Comment: You can also look at Cucumber

Comment: First thanks for your time, I'm bothering you again. I had a look at jBehave but let me explain me with an example : you have an application and you want to test it(Kind of test I've explained above) How you can understand the domain of input of this application considering you are not the programer of this application! Do you have to try all the possible input one by one to figure out all the possible output of this application?